# Rails saving all my fields as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It creates the object, says that it was successfully created, but all fields are saved in the database with nil values. Only `created_at` and `updated_at` are saved normally.

Some methods of my `controllers/admin/categories_controller.rb`

```
  def new
    @admin_category = Category.new
  end

  # GET /admin/categories/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /admin/categories
  # POST /admin/categories.json
  def create
    @admin_category = Category.new(params[:category])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin_category.save
        format.html { redirect_to admin_category_path(@admin_category), notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: admin_category_path(@admin_category) }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @admin_category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /admin/categories/1
  # PATCH/PUT /admin/categories/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin_category.update(admin_category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @admin_category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @admin_category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @admin_category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is my models/category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

This is my routes.br file

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :categories
end
```

My views/admin/categories/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@admin_category, url: admin_categories_path) do |f| %>
  <% if @admin_category.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@admin_category.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this admin_category from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @admin_category.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :is_active %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :is_active %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :main_menu %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :main_menu %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :category_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And when I try to edit, I get this error:

`No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/categories"`

I'm very newbie to Ruby on Rails, so I would apreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with the params that are generated in the server log?

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing `:category` when creating a new Category:

```
def create
  @admin_category = Category.new(params[:category])
```

Change it to `Category.new(user_params)` and try again. This will pass on all parameters you're creating and feed it to the database.

Also, permit the parameters you are trying to pass:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:admin_category).permit(:name, :is_active, :main_menu, :category_id)
end
```

Comment: Tryed this but now I get an error:
    ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError


Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"rNkyZamSR0kckuH+EFTrICn492QTGK55xOqudT6wyHv+z/xpqS+8U5B709xbComevzn/kEMU6/mN8BPVMZwKjw==",
 "category"=>{"name"=>"FirstTest",
 "is_active"=>"1",
 "main_menu"=>"1",
 "category_id"=>"6"},
 "commit"=>"Create Category"}

Comment: Edited my answer. Make sure to change params to user_params as the defined method is called that way.

Comment: It worked for me! But I had to replace `params.require(:admin_category)` for `params.require(:admin_category)`. Anyway, I stil get the error No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/categories"' when I try to update a category. I believe it's because my form_for is using url: (@admin_category, url: admin_categories_path). Any idea?

Comment: Can you get rid of `url: admin_categories path` and simply use `form_for(@admin_category)`? POST (create) and PATCH/PUT (update) don't use the same named helper, as you can see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing.

Answer (score 0):

[Strong Params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters):

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @admin_category = Category.new category_params
   end

   private

   def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :is_active, :main_menu, :category_id)
   end
end
```

--

As a tip, if you're using nested objects with forms, you can pass both objects in an array to create the nested path:

```
#app/views/admin/categories/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [:admin, @admin_category] do |f| %>
```

Comment: It worked for me! But there is still a problem: I still can't edit the category. When I click 'Update Category' it gives me this error: "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument".